# How to get thumb image given a File instance in Kotlin?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, media

**How to get thumb image given a File instance in Kotlin?**

Is it possible to get a tumbnail image from a File instance when the File is a media file?

Comment: Try `MediaMetadataRetriever`: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: @CommonsWare that works only for video and audio files. what about image files?

Comment: You just load the image, using Glide, coil, or your favorite image-loading library. "Thumbnail" would be a matter of the size of your target for loading the image.